# VBA Macro Runs even if cell is Empty

Tags: vba, excel

I'm Quite new to coding VBA in Excel, Just need help with a short script in excel. See Script Below:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("D4:D10")
    Dim CellLocation
    Set CellLocation = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, rng)

         If Not CellLocation Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Current Cell Location is" & CellLocation.Address
            If CellLocation.Value = "True" And CellLocation.Value <> "" And CellLocation.Offset(0, 1) = "Ready" Then
                'Call Initiate_Email_Sending
                MsgBox "Second Trigger"
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If 
End Sub
```

My issue here is that every time i edit a cell (Any cell for that matter) and press enter in the worksheet it would always seem to trigger the second if statement. 
See screenshot of Table below:

[image: Initial Table]

so for example after Editing the Cell B4, and pressing enter it seems to bypass the first If statement and goes directly into the second if statement.

[image: After Editing Cell]

What i wish to achieve here is that i wanted the macro to automatically trigger when Column D has a "True" Status given that Column E has a "Ready" Status and i think that's pretty much it.

What am i doing wrong here? :(

also the formula on Column D is just a dummy formula to simulate auto updating based on Column C's value (Formula is =if(C4=1,"True","false")) See screenshot below.

[Table Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIb6R.png)

Comment: Your second test statement seems redundant. If the value is `TRUE` you already know it is not blank.

Comment: Is the `TRUE` text or the result of a formula/boolean test?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you are trying to do with the macro? Or respond to above lol

Comment: "every time i edit any cell and press enter" - is that any cell whatsoever, or any cell *in the status column*? The code involves `Dependents`, but the formulas involved are nowhere in your post. Can you [edit] to make your question clearer for people that aren't looking at your screen?

Comment: @udearboy the TRUE text in the cell is text from a formula "=if(C4 = 1, "True","False") Basically it's suppose to send an email (Already have a sub for that) when the column C has a status of "True"

Comment: @Mathieu okay i'll try rephrasing the question. sorry i was a bit tired already when creating this question LOL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some import thing before the coding, we need to set the **Formulas** correctly. You can check it by "**Show Formulas(Ctrl+`)**". If the row doesn't contain a right Formulas and then you operate a cell(such the column with 1/2), the operation on **CellLocation** will be ignore, I am not sure if this is a known bug/behavior. Due to the operation is ignore, so the “**Second Trigger**” will show. If we have set the **Formulas** correctly, **CellLocation.Value** will return True or false.

Based on my test, you can just modify your if statement(**If the Formulas right configured**):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("D4:D100")
    Dim CellLocation
    Set CellLocation = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, rng)

         If Not CellLocation Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Previous Cell Location is " & CellLocation.Address
            'MsgBox "Previous Cell Offset's value is " & CellLocation.Offset(0, 1).Text & CellLocation.Offset(0, 1).Value

If IsEmpty(Target) Or IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, -1)) Then Exit Sub

            If CellLocation.Value = "True" And CellLocation.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Ready" Then
                'Call Initiate_Email_Sending
                MsgBox "Second Trigger"
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

If the Formulas doesn't set correctly, **we cannot relay on** the If Statement in the code.

Reference for [apply Formulas without dragging](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/867-excel-apply-formula-to-entire-column-row.html).

Comment: Hi Seiya i tried this out and still didn't fix my issue. it still triggers the second trigger if i type anything on any cells in the sheet :(

Comment: I tried to copy this to a new excel file without any content and after editing any cell and pressing enter the second trigger still keeps getting triggered. Any thoughts? :(

Comment: Do you check your formulas? It must be set correctly. If you doesn't configure the formulas, it should always pupup the "Trigger"

Comment: Pay attention to my Highlight text.

Comment: I copied the script you have given into a new Worksheet and even though there aren't any values in the worksheet when i try to input anything on any cell and press enter it triggers the second trigger. even just pressing on delete and enter on any cell it triggers the second trigger.

Comment: The second trigger will always until you set a valid formulas. Do not rely on the code directly. I found you always ignore(or not get) my highlight text and above comment.

Comment: Hi @seiya I have checked the formula for Columns D4 to D10, added screenshot above, are these not valid formulas? Sorry to be a bit hard headed still new to this, hoping for your patience on my issue :(

Comment: Sorry for delay reply. Have update the answer with new code line

Answer (score -2):

There does not seem to be an empty string in the empty cell. There is a few ways to test if there is nothing in the cell, i.e. null,nothing,empty, empty-string, etc. [please read here a bit](http://allenbrowne.com/vba-NothingEmpty.html). Basically

Hope this helps.